# Handle JSONObject inside other JSONObject

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I want to send json, which have another json object inside, like this

```
{
     "key1": "value1",
     "key2": "valu2",
     "content": {
         "nestedkey1": "nestedValue1",
         "nestedkey2": "nestedValue2" 
     }
```

}

Object inside doesn't have any java representation, just string in json-format. How it can be correctly converted?

My approach is not correct, I always receive empty string for nested json. I used Map for this nested object, but empty map again.

```
public class Instance {

private String key1;

private int key2;

private String content;

public String getKey1 {
    return key1;
}

public void setKey1(String key1) {
    this.key1 = key1;
}

public BigDecimal getKey2() {
    return key2;
}

public void setKey2(BigDecimal key2) {
    this.key2 = key2;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the JSON serialization being done? If you're not using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), then you should be.

Jackson can take a `Map` and translate it to JSON just like you want, without any additional configuration. On the other hand, if you're using the Jersey JSON plugin, you'd have to write a subclass of `Map`, and add JAXB annotations to it - kind of a pain in the ass.